# Валютные котировки JSON с сайта в JAVA

Tags: java, json

Всем привет!
Ни как не могу получить ответ JSON с сайта котировок.
*Вот пример с сайта* :

`{"USD":{"RUB":73.86,"JPY":108.72}}` ,  как мне правильно его обработать для корректной работы в коде ниже?

*это мой код:*

```java
    private void fetchData() {
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_RECENT_PRODUCT, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.failed_fetch_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        List<Product> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Product>>() {
                        }.getType());

                        // adding contacts to contacts list
                        productList.clear();
                        productList.addAll(items);

                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
```

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Ошибка какая-то? Если да - добавьте логи оной

Comment: @ЮрийСПб - Как я понял , ошибка в преобразовании JSONObject и JSONArray.   `INFO: Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"USD":{"RUB":73.84}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: А, у вас же не список, а вы пытаетесь список парсить. Т.е. должно быть, наверное, как-то так: `Product item = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Product.class);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб - после замены на это  `Product item = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Product.class);`  начинает ругаться  `productList.clear();
productList.addAll(items);` ,как я понимаю это проблемы с адаптером ?

Comment: Сложно сказать. Судя по JSON - у вас там всего один элемент и RecyclerView тут не нужен. Скорее всего вы что-то совсем не то делаете. А ругается у вас наверное потому, что вы добавляете один элемент, а не список (стоит приводить конкретную ошибку, чтобы люди не гадали.). Попробуйте использовать `add` вместо `addAll`